# Vue.js: Why isn't my list isn't rendering with v-for directive?

Tags: javascript, list, for-loop, vue.js, pug

I am trying to render a list stored in data within the same component. Console keeps telling me there is a 'module build fail'.

Any idea why the list will not render?

This is what I have so far:

```
    <template lang="pug">

    .work
        .work__top
            .content
                h1 Work To-Do List
                p.date Monday, 19th September
        .work__search
            search
        .work__taskList
            ul
                li(v-for="task in tasks")
                    {{task.complete}}

</template>

<script>

    import Search from './components/Search.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            'search': Search,
        },
      data() {
            return {
                tasks: [
                    {complete: false, label: 'Finish report'}
                ]
            }
      },
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the `{{task.complete}}` text on a line of its own like that is not valid syntax in pug.

You can put `{{task.complete}}` on the same line as `li(v-for="task in tasks")`. You could provide an element to house the `task.complete` text (like `span {{task.complete}}`). Or, you could add a `.` to the end of the `li` line to allow you to provide a block of text in the following line.

[Here's a codepen with examples of those three solutions.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMjBOV)